# Shortest distance to the cardinalspline spline curve from the outside point in c++

Tags: c++, c, math, bezier, curve

I need to find shortest distance from any given point outside of the curve to cardinalspline curve
 Can I have any reference link or any equations can help me on this.
following is the reference link the way i want to implement

Thanks 
nikhil

Comment: maybe you can ask this in Mathematics StackExchange site http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure of what you want. Maybe [this](http://www.it.uom.gr/teaching/linearalgebra/NumericalRecipiesInC/c3-3.pdf) can help. It will give you the analytical form f(x,y) = 0 of the cardinal spline from your original set of (xi, y(xi)). You can easily find the shortest distance between a point p(x,y) and the spline studying the first two derivatives of sqrt((px-fx)² + (py-fy)²). Hope this helps.